# Java Swing Key Event base

Tags: java, swing, key, shortcut

In one of my menus, one menuItem's shortcut key is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Greater</kbd>

code for that is  KeyEvent.VK_GREATER, Event.CTRL_MASK

but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Greater</kbd> it's not working....
Can any one please suggest?

Comment: difficult to answer if you don't post some code.

Comment: both putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_GREATER, Event.CTRL_MASK));

Comment: and putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_GREATER, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));.... is not working

Answer (score 2):

Thought this rather old nuisance had been fixed .. obviously not ;-)

In the ol' days, it was only safe to use keyStrokes which have VK_Something with Something being accessible without shift *on an american* keyboard layout. That means, using keybinding to keys which have positions (w/out shift or even via gr) different from that base, is either highly keyboard layout dependent or highly unstable - better don't use.

```
   // technical binding to "Greater" on a German keyboard  
   other.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control shift LESS"));

   // BUT ... not really, its localized description is
   Str-Umschalt-Kleiner als
```

Comment: +1 for interesting answer. Just to check in the 'technical binding' you have given should there be LESS?

Comment: @Boro, on a German keyboard there is, on a us keyboard probably not (going by wikipedia, too lazy for switching mine and trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out my code. Here all is fine.

**THIS example is not appropriate to the problem but I gave it first and (was nagged for it) thus it is left here for reference. For the appropriate one, i.e. setting accelerator on a menu item, please see EDIT1 below.**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CtrlGreaterTestInaccurateAnswer extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private KeyListener kL = new KeyAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            super.keyReleased(e);
        System.out.println("keyReleased KeyEvent.VK_GREATER=" + KeyEvent.VK_GREATER
                + "; e.getKeyCode()=" + e.getKeyCode()
                + "; e.getKeyChar()=" + e.getKeyChar()
                + "; e.isControlDown()=" + e.isControlDown()
                + "; e.isShiftDown()=" + e.isShiftDown() 
                + "; (int)'.'="+(int)'.' +"; (int)'>'="+(int)'>');
        if(e.isControlDown()    && e.getKeyChar() == '>')
            System.out.println("keyReleased ctrl + greater");
        }
    };

    public CtrlGreaterTestInaccurateAnswer()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(kL);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                CtrlGreaterTestInaccurateAnswer f = new CtrlGreaterTestInaccurateAnswer();
                f.setSize(400, 400);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From what I have observed KeyEvent.VK_GREATER returns 160, and the code returned when pressing '>' is 46, i.e. the same as pressing '.'. Thus, if you use the getKeyCode method for detection you have a problem here.

**EDIT1 (Appropriate example):**
Setting accelerator for CTRL + >. Please notice that still the accelerator will say Ctrl+Shift-PERIOD (Ctrl+Shift+.)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CtrlGreaterTest extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CtrlGreaterTest()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Menu1");
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem();
        menuItem1.setAction(onCtrlGreaterAction);
        menuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, 
                KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK));         
        //or use this
        //menuItem1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl shift PERIOD"));
        menu1.add(menuItem1);

        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem();
        menuItem2.setAction(onCtrlAAction);
        menuItem2.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 
                KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK)); 

        System.out.println("KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD| KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK="
                +(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD| KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK)
                + "; KeyEvent.VK_GREATER="+(KeyEvent.VK_GREATER) 
                + "; (int)'>'="+(int)'>');
        menu1.add(menuItem2);       
        menuBar.add(menu1);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
    private AbstractAction onCtrlGreaterAction = new AbstractAction("CTRL + > Action")
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("onCtrlGreaterAction actionPerformed OI");
        }
    };

    private AbstractAction onCtrlAAction = new AbstractAction("CTRL + a Action")
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("onCtrlAAction actionPerformed AI");
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                CtrlGreaterTest f = new CtrlGreaterTest();
                f.setSize(400, 400);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this is it :)

Comment: Thnx for the prompt response Boro!!. Used the above code and getting the same result... just want to know why it is coming like that and and is there any alternate way to resolve it....

Comment: @Ashish - as to the why, see my answer. As to to the alternative - none, to my knowledgs. Would love to be proven wrong, though :-)

Comment: @Ashish @kleopatra I think that you never can go wrong with using getKeyChar(), at least I have never observed a situation when it didn't work which can happen when relaying on getKeyCode(). Thus only thing I can recommend here is either to use getKeyChar() always or always for non-digit & non-letter characters.

Comment: keybindings are always to a KeyStroke, there is no getKeyChar in KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(whateverParameters) -- or maybe I'm missing something in what you mean?

Comment: @Ashish @kleopatra please notice I have updated my answer to reflect an appropriate solution to the problem which works for me. From what @kleopatra is saying it might be keyboard dependent.

Comment: @kleopatra as to your comment about bindings you are completely right I was talking about a solution to a different problem, i.e. use of a key listener to capture ctrl + '>'. My bad.

Comment: Can the person who gave me -1 please explain what is wrong so I can correct it?